# TypeScript: Access external `this` in an accessor in an object literal field

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have the code

```
class A {
    a = 1;

    o = {
        get b() {
            return this.a; //<--
        }
    }
}
```

The `this` pointed to is actually referring to `o` whereas I really want to access the instance of `A`.

Is what I want possible in this format? (Without creating a function and alias)

Comment: This is not valid class syntax to begin with. In ES2015, you can only define class methods, not properties like this. All your properties would have to be initialized in the constructor (ES.Next proposes a `static` variable slot, but that's a different story).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*without creating a function*". You want a getter, right?

Comment: @nils Yeah, it's actually TypeScript. I've fixed the title. I guess this could be a limitation in the way properties are defined in TypeScript. @bergi I meant without wrapping the object literal in a function scope in order to alias `this`.

Comment: @billc.cn my bad, I didn't see the tag.

Comment: @billc.cn: The object literal *is* already wrapped in a function scope - namely your constructor's scope. Not syntactically maybe, but semantically - and you'd make your life a lot easier by just reflecting that in your syntax.

Comment: @nils No, it's really my fault. I didn't know there's this syntax difference until you pointed it out. I guess this is technically not an issue in ES6 as it is trivial to alias `this` in a constructor.

Comment: @Bergi It's the TypeScript syntax defined by Microsoft though. I along can't do anything about it. I might submit an issue if there's no workaround, but based on experience, this may never get resolved.

Comment: The "workaround" is just not to use syntactic sugar where it doesn't buy you anything :-) Put it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is will end up giving you the same api, though you have to break out classes to do it:

```
class o {
 constructor(private owner: t) {}
 get b() { return this.owner.a; }
}

class t {
 a = 1
 o = new o(this)
}
```

Comment: I like the full on OO approach :)